# How do I prove relation involving inequalities is transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-proofs

I have only written proofs that prove relations using equality are transitive.  I have no idea how to manipulate equations with inequalities.

R = {(x, y) | x − y > 1} is a relation on ℝ
Claim: R is transitive 
Proof: 
Choose x, y, z ∈ ℝ and assume R(x,y) and R(y,z) 
So x - y > 1 and y - z > 1 
Stuck..

I know I need to prove x - z > 1 but I dont know how to get there.

---

I figured it out thanks to the replies.  I just had to add the two inequalities.

Choose x, y, z ∈ ℝ and assume R(x,y) and R(y,z) 
So x - y > 1 and y - z > 1 
(x - y) + (y - z) > 2 
x - z > 2 > 1 
Therefore R(x,z)

Comment: You have to prove R(x,z), i.e. that $x - z > 1$

Comment: $x-z = x - y + y - z=(x - y)+(y-z) > 1+1 > ?$

Comment: Adding
$$
x - y > 1
$$
and
$$
y - z > 1
$$
memberwise, we get
$$
x - z > 2 > 1.
$$